# Custom C++ Quaternion Rotation Not Working Correctly

Tags: c++, rotation, vector-graphics, quaternions

In my code, I have a quaternion that is used for rotation for a camera for the player.  Rotation itself seems to work fine, but my directional vectors for moving and to rotate on do not rotate correctly.

**Quaternion Multiplication:**

```
Quaternion Quaternion::operator*(Vector3 other) const
{

    float x_ = w * other.x + y * other.z - z * other.y;
    float y_ = w * other.y + z * other.x - x * other.z;
    float z_ = w * other.z + x * other.y - y * other.x;
    float w_ = -x * other.x - y * other.y - z * other.z;

    return Quaternion(x_, y_, z_, w_);

}

Quaternion Quaternion::operator*(Quaternion other) const
{

    Vector4 r = other.getValues();

    float x_ = x * r.w + w * r.x + y * r.z - z * r.y;
    float y_ = y * r.w + w * r.y + z * r.x - x * r.z;
    float z_ = z * r.w + w * r.z + x * r.y - y * r.x;
    float w_ = w * r.w - x * r.x - y * r.y - z * r.z;

    return Quaternion(x_, y_, z_, w_);

}
```

**Conjugate Function**

```
Quaternion Quaternion::conjugate() const
{

    return Quaternion(-x, -y, -z, w);

}
```

**Vector Rotation:**

```
void Vector3::rotate(Quaternion rotation)
{

    Quaternion rotated = rotation * *this * rotation.conjugate();

    x = rotated.getValues().x;
    y = rotated.getValues().y;
    z = rotated.getValues().z;

}
```

**Sample Directional Vector:**

```
Vector3 Quaternion::getRight() const
{

    Vector3 right(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    right.rotate(*this);

    return right;

}
```

If I have the camera rotated exactly 90 degrees around the y-axis and I print out the values of the right vector, x is 0.000796229, y is 0 and z is -1.  In this case, x should be 0 and z should be a positive 1.

I have been browsing Google and others' code for the past few days trying to find what I am doing wrong, but I cannot find anything wrong.

**UPDATE:**

I ended up deciding to just incorporate GLM into my math classes and after some changing of things, everything works as it should.

Comment: Indenting all your code by another 4 spaces will make it easier to read

Comment: Can you give an example (numbers!) of things going wrong, ie your input, output, and expected result.

Comment: @DannyRuijters I include a specific example in the post.

Comment: Definitely not part of the issue, but you can use `other.x` instead of `other.getX()` to make the code sightly easier to read.

Comment: show the `conjugate` function

Comment: Also try debugging your code. go over the algorithm in the debugger and see where it diverges from your expectations

Comment: @MattMcNabb I tried the debugger a few times, I am not an expert at using it, but by manully debugging I understand what happens, as shown in the example.  I added the conjugate function to the post.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I changed them.

Comment: Are you saying `getRight` is giving the wrong result? seems kinda important what `*this` is before that

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deciding to just incorporate GLM into my math classes and after some changing of things, everything works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

In your vector rotation replace the first line by

```
Quaternion rotated = rotation * Quaternion(this->x, this->y, this->z, 0) * 
    rotation.conjugate();
```

Explanation: Quaternion multiplications are not commutative, which means that Q * v does not equal v * Q, with v being a Quaternion with w=0.

Comment: I put this into code and it didn't change anything, I had the exact same results.  I tried to change the order of this multiplication and what was interesting was some ways fixed the wrong direction problem to an extent that they were just the opposite at times, but caused a rotation on the z-axis that wasn't supposed to happen.  Thanks for the help anyways.